# Using MvcSiteMapProvider + DI + Repository pattern = repository object is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, mvcsitemapprovider, ninject.web.mvc

In my application I have a register of projects.
To access these projects is the url: `/project/{url-project}`

```
the value of `{url-project}` is defined in the registration of the project!
```

I use [this project](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) to generate the path, but as the "register project" is dynamic had to implement it manually as shows [this article](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dynamic%20sitemaps&version=1).

**So I did:**

```
public class ProjectDetailsDynamicNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IProjectRepository ProjectRepository { get; set; }

    #region Overrides of DynamicNodeProviderBase

    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
    {
        // Build value 
        var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();
        var listDB = (from p in ProjectRepository.Query()
                      select new { p.Name, p.ID });

        // Create a node for each album 
        foreach (var project in listDB.ToList())
        {
            var node = new DynamicNode { Title = project.Name };
            node.RouteValues.Add("id", project.ID);

            returnValue.Add(node);
        }

        // Return 
        return returnValue;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**In my Mvc.sitemap**

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Projetos" controller="Project" action="Index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Novo Projeto" controller="Project" action="Create" />
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Projeto" action="About" dynamicNodeProvider="BindSolution.Infra.ProjectDetailsDynamicNodeProvider, BindSolution" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

### Problem

My problem is `ProjectRepository` which is always null!

```
kernel.Bind<IProjectRepository>().To<ProjectRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

But in my setup Ninject is correct!
This repository **is used in the controller and it works perfectly**!

### Attemps

I tried to inject this dependency via the constructor but the result was the same!

```
public class ProjectDetailsDynamicNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    public IProjectRepository ProjectRepository { get; set; }

    public ProjectDetailsDynamicNodeProvider(IProjectRepository projectRepository)
    {
        ProjectRepository = projectRepository
    }

    #region Overrides of DynamicNodeProviderBase

    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
    {
        // Build value 
        var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();
        var listDB = (from p in ProjectRepository.Query()
                      select new { p.Name, p.ID });

        // Create a node for each album 
        foreach (var project in listDB.ToList())
        {
            var node = new DynamicNode { Title = project.Name };
            node.RouteValues.Add("id", project.ID);

            returnValue.Add(node);
        }

        // Return 
        return returnValue;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: How do you setup your controllers to use Ninject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this question is similar to yours:
[MVC3, Ninject, MvcSiteMapProvider - How to inject dependency to overridden method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933995/mvc3-ninject-mvcsitemapprovider-how-to-inject-dependency-to-overridden-metho)

Which means that basically you there isn't a good solution.