# Injection using NInject in ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a small problem which, hopefully, you will help me put behind.

I am using a `MvcSiteMapProvider`, and I want to define visibility for each node using access to a DB via a service interface.

```
 public class AreaSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider : MvcSiteMapProvider.Extensibility.ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider
{   
[Inject]
public ISecurityService _SecurityService {get;set;}
        public AreaSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider()
    {
        
    }
    public bool IsVisible(SiteMapNode node, HttpContext context, IDictionary<string, object> sourceMetadata)
    {
        MvcSiteMapNode thisNode = node as MvcSiteMapNode;
        return _SecurityService.CalculateNodeVisibility(thisNode,context.Cache["someValueIHaveStoredHere"])
        
    }
}
```

However, my `_SecurityService` member is always `null`. Any suggestions? I accept any type of directions, including getting rid of my injection and going another way.

Comment: how the ninject kernel creates AreaSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ISecurityService` is `null`, because in this case, Ninject is not managing the creation of `MvcSiteMapProvider` (in MVC app, Ninject resolves dependencies wired from controller *root*, because it manages the creation of controllers - it overrides the default method for creation controllers).

Options to resolve your issue:

**1)**
Use Ninject as service locator. **Not recommended!**, *as it is widely considered to be an anti-pattern (but it depends...)*.

```
var app = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance as NinjectHttpApplication;
var service = app.Kernel.Get<ISecurityService>();
```

**2)** Read *R. Gloor's* answer on similar question: [MVC3, Ninject, MvcSiteMapProvider - How to inject dependency to overridden method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933995/mvc3-ninject-mvcsitemapprovider-how-to-inject-dependency-to-overridden-metho) and do it his way.

Comment: Well, I have, once again, reviewed the structure initially used for the architecture, and what do you know, the use of the above mentioned "anti-practice" is in place in one particular method implementation. Therefore i have inserted the needed binding there, and used the User object to propagate the info down in my chain of command. So i will mark this as an accurate answer, with mention that bellow response was also very useful. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

1. The siteMapNodeVisibilityProvider is **NOT** configured in the web.config
2. There is a binding for `ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider`

Comment: Please develop on 1. Thanks.

Comment: What i mean is, would you have me remove it completely from web.config? Would it still work after that?

Comment: Look at the MvcSiteMapProvider source code: When it is configured in the web.config then the Ninject binding is ignored.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up! I will dig deeper and see how this could have turned up, in a separate project, and get back to you. Cheers!