# Error occured by using Ninject-Injection in ASP.NET MVC 4 MemberShip-Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, membership-provider

I have a self implemented MembershipProvider using in a MVC 4 web app. In the provider i want to use a service for accessing the relevant data. The service instance should be injected by Ninject using property injection. But there are problem with the injection. From the AccountController the correct membership provider was called, but the instance variable is null.

Is there a problem whiel the membership provider is created by the asp.net life cycle?

Comment: Show is your code, brother. How did you configure this. How does your provider look. How those the consumer look.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10394860/11635

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inject repository to custom membership provider with Ninject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596441/inject-repository-to-custom-membership-provider-with-ninject)

Comment: Thanks Ruben. That's the answer!