# NHibernate throwing Session is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, ninject

I'm flapping in the wind, so I thought I'd ask here... Please let me know if this is obvious and has been answered before.

I'm building an MVC 3 site which works fine while I'm running it with one user, where I click through the pages.  However, if I madly hit refresh, eventually I hit a "Session is closed".

I've isolated out almost all of all my repository to try to get to the bottom, so I know have it erroring on the homepage.  The only thing that is being called in the repository is get the user's name from a database table.

I'm using Postgres as a database, and the ASP.NET Membership provider from NauckIT.  The main database is also Postgres (but another database).

The session management is done using the following code:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory = 
             NHibernateHelper.GetSessionFactory();

    public MvcApplication()
    {
        this.BeginRequest += MvcApplication_BeginRequest;
        this.EndRequest += MvcApplication_EndRequest;
    }

    void MvcApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(SessionFactory.OpenSession());
    }
    void MvcApplication_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory).Dispose();
    }
}
```

The code that get's the login information is:

```
    public Login GetCurrentLogin()
    {
        return Session.Query<Login>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.UserID == UserAccessRepository.UserID);
    }
```

The `UserAccessRepository` simply gets the `userid` from the forms authentication cookie.

Session is injected into the repository using:

```
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<NHUserRepository>();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<ILeagueRepository>().To<NHLeagueRepository>().InThreadScope();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<ISession>()
            .ToMethod(m => MvcApplication.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession())
```

The sessionfactory comes from:

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {       var rawConfig = new Configuration();
                rawConfig.SetNamingStrategy(new PostgresNamingStrategy());
                var configuration = Fluently.Configure(rawConfig)
                    .Database(PostgreSQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(ConnectionString).ShowSql().Dialect("NHibernate.Dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect"))
                    .Mappings(m =>
                                m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Event>(new AutoMapConfiguration())
                )).ExposeConfiguration(cfg => 
                    cfg.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web")
                _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
                Debug.WriteLine("Built SessionFactory");
            }
            return _sessionFactory;
```

To be clear, it works fine in the standard instance where I click through the pages, but when I madly hit F5, I get the session closed issue.

UPDATE:
Not sure if it's relevant, but the main place I'm seeing this in the `BaseController`, from within the `OnActionExecuting` method.  It seems to have cleared up in the methods above.

Comment: My first question would be: why the whole `Begin/EndRequest` setup instead of injecting per-session lifetime scoped `ISession` into the controller?

Comment: first example I found of session per request... happy for an alternative.. got a link?

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor that's a pretty common way to do it... not saying it's the best way, but I definitely see it all over the place.

Comment: @SonicTheLichen Weird, it's the first time I've seen it. It *feels* more straightforward to inject the dependency with correct lifetime scope... But whatever :) Anyway, [here's a simple link I've googled with Ninject + ASP.NET MVC](http://www.shahnawazk.com/2010/12/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-3.html); I don't know Ninject, but I'm sure there's an option to set the dependency lifetime scope to 'per HTTP request'.

Comment: Ninject has InRequestScope()

Comment: tried everything, changed to using the "Basic approach" from Ayende http://ayende.com/blog/4101/do-you-need-a-framework, still get the error, any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't `CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory).Dispose();` dispose the session factory and not the session?

Comment: @ta.speot.is The Unbind method returns the ISession object from the current context, that's then disposed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `InThreadScope()` in a web app. Use `InRequestScope()`. EDIT Have a read of [Object Scopes](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) - its been updated recently and not knowing it backwards is going to waste your time sooner or later!

If you're looking to make stuff work across a membership provider and request processing, you need to search for Ninject Custom Provider (maybe something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10394860/11635)).

Comment: The membership provider is separate, and uses direct ADO.NET not NHibernate, therefore the Session is not used for this portion.  I'll try replacing that and report back

Comment: @Martin Good - that's one less source of confusion for you so. Bottom line is you need to a) bind stuff that needs `Dispose`al in a scope other than [unspecified (which is implicitly Transient) or] Transient but b) doing stuff `InThreadScope()` both prevents the Disposal at the end of the request and causes a a random Disposal at some point in the future (and usage of such object across multiple requests that just happen to have been dispatched [for some of their processing] on the same thread

Comment: :D that worked, had to change everything to InRequestScope.  I may be able to reduce that over time with some optimisation (i.e work out those that actually need to be InRequestScope and those that don't), but for now it works.