# NHibernate session is closed when refreshing page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, nhibernate

This is another strange problem I've encountered this days!!! I've created and MVC 4 app using nhibernate. and added a filter attribute named [LoggingNHibernateSessionAttribute] on my HomeController which manages session for each action. I've followed 'ASP.NET MVC4 and the Web API published by Apress'.

```
public class LoggingNHibernateSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IActionLogHelper _actionLogHelper;
    private readonly IActionExceptionHandler _actionExceptionHandler;
    private readonly IActionTransactionHelper _actionTransactionHelper;

    public LoggingNHibernateSessionAttribute()
        : this(WebContainerManager.Get<IActionLogHelper>(),
        WebContainerManager.Get<IActionExceptionHandler>(),
        WebContainerManager.Get<IActionTransactionHelper>())
    {
    }

    public LoggingNHibernateSessionAttribute(
        IActionLogHelper actionLogHelper,
        IActionExceptionHandler actionExceptionHandler,
        IActionTransactionHelper actionTransactionHelper)
    {
        _actionLogHelper = actionLogHelper;
        _actionExceptionHandler = actionExceptionHandler;
        _actionTransactionHelper = actionTransactionHelper;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExectingContext)
    {
        _actionLogHelper.LogEntry(actionExectingContext.ActionDescriptor);
        _actionTransactionHelper.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        _actionTransactionHelper.EndTransaction(actionExecutedContext);
        _actionTransactionHelper.CloseSession();
        _actionExceptionHandler.HandleException(actionExecutedContext);
        _actionLogHelper.LogExit(actionExecutedContext.ActionDescriptor);
    }
}
```

ActionTransactionHelper

```
  public class ActionTransactionHelper : IActionTransactionHelper
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private readonly ICurrentSessionContextAdapter _currentSessionContextAdapter;

    public ActionTransactionHelper(
        ISessionFactory sessionFactory,
        ICurrentSessionContextAdapter currentSessionContextAdapter)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        _currentSessionContextAdapter = currentSessionContextAdapter;
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        var session = _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.BeginTransaction();
        }
    }

    public bool TransactionHandled { get; private set; }

    public void EndTransaction(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var session = _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();

        if (session == null) return;
        if (!session.Transaction.IsActive) return;

        if (filterContext.Exception == null)
        {
            session.Flush();
            session.Transaction.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            session.Transaction.Rollback();
        }

        TransactionHandled = true;
    }

    public bool SessionClosed { get; private set; }

    public void CloseSession()
    {
        if (_currentSessionContextAdapter.HasBind(_sessionFactory))
        {
            var session = _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
            session.Close();
            session.Dispose();
            _currentSessionContextAdapter.Unbind(_sessionFactory);

            SessionClosed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

when run the app, I can save an entity in the dataBase. but when I hit refresh button and exception thrown indication session is closed.

I don't know why this happens. (I searched and find this [NHibernate throwing Session is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657224/nhibernate-throwing-session-is-closed) but couldn't solve my problem).

in my NinjectConfigurator I added inRequestScope() to all of injections but no answer. I checked when I refresh the page session will be opened. but I donnow why it say session is closed?!

**UPDATE:**

when I first run the app. I can create a new member. but when I hit the refresh button, the session will be closed unexpectedly!!
first run:

1. everything works well

after hitting refresh button:

1. a new session bind to the current context.
2. the new session will be injected the repository (session is open)
3. the ActionTransactionHelper calls beginTransaction()
   4- customMembership createUser (....) called
   5- but when the _userRepositoy.save(user)called in the repository session is closed!!!!

note:but when still endTransaction and closeSession isn't called. but how session is closed?
 if I comment closeSession() in onActionExecute(). session alway is open and everything woks well if refresh the page.
 I checked a lot and tried different way I knew. it only happens when for the second time I want to do CRUD operations with my customMembership.

for other entities it works like a charm! 
[image]
I have upoaded my sample code. for testing just create and empty database and change connection string. then go to localHost:*****/api/categories (user and pass doesn't required)

Download sample project:
Size: 47 MB
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o63wjng5f799fii/Hashem-MVC4ServicesBook.rar

size: 54 MB
Zip Format: https://www.dropbox.com/s/smrsbz4cbtznx1y/Hashem-MVC4ServicesBook2.zip

Answer (score 1):

A very important thing here, could be the nature of the NHibernate. The NHibernate and its `Session` are in the ASP.NET MVC living longer, then could be expected. I mean not only inside of the

- ActionExecuting (Controller Action starts)
- ActionExecuted (the View or Redirect is called)

Session in fact must live also through the phase of **rendering**. Because, we could load some *proxy* in the "Action()" but its collection, could be `lazily` loaded only during the `View` rendering. So even in these phases `Session` must be opened *(the same Session from the request begining)*

- ResultExecuting (the proxy could start to be loaded only here)
- ResultExecuted (almost all is done, let's close the session)

Other words... **keep the session opened throught the complete Request**. From authorization untill the content is rendered.

NOTE: Anohter hint, *just to be sure that all is ok*, I am using this scenario *(maybe you do as well)*:

1. Client FORM is about to send the data to server. The method is POST, the Action is Update()
2. Sent FORM is coming to server, Action Update() is triggerred - *all the transactions stuff is in place (as described above)*
3. Once NHibernate persists the data into DB, the Update() action ends, and is redirected to action

   - `Detail()` if all is ok or
   - `Edit()` if something goes wrong
4. The users Browser was redirected to action Detail or Edit. So if user does REFRESH, the Detail or Edit is refreshed. The `Update()` is not called at all (it is a POST method)

In fact, the step *1.* was one of the Actions `Detail` or `Edit`. In this case, we would face this issue already...

Answer (score 0):

You have this error since **Asp.Net MVC does not create a new instance of `LoggingNHibernateSessionAttribute` every request.** It creates a new instance when you request an action first time and then uses this instance in the future.

The behaviour is the following:

1. First invocation of `Post` -> new instance of 'LoggingNHibernateSession' is created
2. First invocation of `Put` -> another one instance of 'LoggingNHibernateSession' is created
3. Second invocation of `Put` -> instance of 'LoggingNHibernateSession' from previous step is used
4. First invocation of `Delete` -> another one instance of 'LoggingNHibernateSession' is created

   ```
   [LoggingNHibernateSession]
   public JsonResult Post(Dto data)
   {
       /* ... */
   }

   [LoggingNHibernateSession]
   public JsonResult Put(int id, Dto data)
   {
       /* ... */
   }

   [LoggingNHibernateSession]
   public JsonResult Delete(int id)
   {
       /* ... */
   }
   ```

**It can be solved using `Func<IActionLogHelper>` instead of `IActionLogHelper` in the constructor.** An instance of `IActionLogHelper` can be initialised within `OnActionExecuting` method.

```
public class LoggingNHibernateSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /* your code */
    private readonly Func<IActionTransactionHelper> _getActionTransactionHelper;
    private IActionTransactionHelper _actionTransactionHelper;

    public LoggingNHibernateSessionAttribute()
        : this(WebContainerManager.Get<IActionLogHelper>(),
        WebContainerManager.Get<IActionExceptionHandler>(),
        () => WebContainerManager.Get<IActionTransactionHelper>())
    {
    }

    public LoggingNHibernateSessionAttribute(
        IActionLogHelper actionLogHelper,
        IActionExceptionHandler actionExceptionHandler,
        Func<IActionTransactionHelper> getActionTransactionHelper)
    {
        _actionLogHelper = actionLogHelper;
        _actionExceptionHandler = actionExceptionHandler;
        _getActionTransactionHelper = getActionTransactionHelper;
        _actionTransactionHelper = null;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExectingContext)
    {
        _actionTransactionHelper = _getActionTransactionHelper();
        _actionLogHelper.LogEntry(actionExectingContext.ActionDescriptor);
        _actionTransactionHelper.BeginTransaction();
    }

    /* your code */
}
```

Comment: I think it may because of that. would you explain more about your solution?

Comment: Usually instance of IoC container is created in `Application_Start` and disposed in `Application_End`. So, you can create a function that resolves dependency every time you invoke it (it is similar to lazy loading) and returns a new instance of `IActionTransactionHelper` every request (`OnActionExecuting`).

Comment: @HashemAboonajmi, Could you provide a *.zip archive since RAR isn't free.

Comment: thanks for your help and devoting time. zip format added. consider only my customMembership has this issue.